# CSV to JavaScript Objects Date parsing issue with node.js - zeros are dropped

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, amazon-s3

**Overview**

*Microservice A* periodically downloads a CSV from an SFTP server and uploads it to an S3 bucket. The date strings in the CSV file (both on the server and in the S3 bucket) are valid:

`2018-08-20T10:45:00`

*Microservice B* downloads the CSV from the S3 bucket. The data is transformed into JSON with the following code:

```
   import * as parser from 'csv-parse';

   const streamFromS3 = (params: any) => 
      s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

  const streamToJSON = (stream: NodeJS.ReadableStream): Promise<any[]> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const csvParser = parser({
        relax: true,
        relax_column_count: true,
        columns: true,
        skip_lines_with_error: true,
        skip_empty_lines: true,
        skip_lines_with_empty_values: true,
      });

      const jsonArray: any[] = [];

      stream.pipe(csvParser)
        .on('data', (data: any) => {
        jsonArray.push(data);
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        resolve(jsonArray);
      });
    });
  };
```

After this the data is written to MongoDB in bulk:

```
  mapLocationsFromJson = (json: any[]) =>
    Promise.all(json.map(j => this.mapLocation(j)))

mapLocation = (json: any) => {
    const {
      CID: companyId,
      LocID: clinicId,
      Location: clinicName,
      Addr1: address,
      Addr2: address2,
      DateCreated: dateCreated,
      City: city,
      ZipCode: zipcode,
      Phone: phone,
      LocationLongName: longName,
      CoName: companyName,
  } = json;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    const location = new Location({ clinicId, longName, dateCreated companyId, clinicName, location: { address, address2, city, zipcode }, companyName, phone });
    return location.save();
}
```

and I periodically get the following Date validation error:

```
message: 'Cast to Date failed for value "2018-08-2T10:45:00" at path "startTime"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"2018-08-2T10:45:00"',
        kind: 'Date',
        value: '2018-08-2T10:45:00',
        path: 'startTime',
        reason: [Object] } },
  _message: 'Availability validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError'
```

Because the date is invalid - the date string is now `2018-08-2T10:45:00` and is missing the ending 0 after the 2.

**EDIT:** The date is properly formatted in the `stream.on('data')` block:

`2018-08-20T10:45:00`

**EDIT:**:

I have attempted to manually transform each data in the `.on('data'` block:

```
stream.pipe(csvParser)
      .on('data', (data: any) => {
        if (data.startTime) {
          const copy = data;
          const formattedDate = moment(data.startTime).toISOString();
          copy.startTime = formattedDate;
          jsonArray.push(copy);
        } else {
          jsonArray.push(data);
        }
```

Still with no luck.

Why is the 0 being dropped and how can I work around this?

Comment: can you provide a snippet of the code that stores the JSON to MongoDB? Also, can you try to parse the date in your `.on('data')` callback? this might be helpful for debugging.

Comment: I just added the code that writes to mongodb, I'm parsing the data on the stream.on('data') method now.

Comment: css-parser can be used as a command line tool; have you tried to execute it directly in the terminal and see what is it returning? Also, use the debugger, it is your friend (`--inspect`) https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: It is indeed my friend, however this service is running remotely in a kubernetes cluster and it isn't as easy to debug.

Comment: Does it fail on all entries?